# Weighted mean of complex exponential function using NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, complex, broken-code

I have defined the following functions:

```
γ[r_, v_, rDet_] := 
  Which[
   Abs[r - v tDet] >= rDet, 0, 
   r + v tDet <= rDet, π, 
   True, ArcCos[((v tDet)^2 + r^2 - rDet^2)/(2 v tDet r)]];
ρ[r_, v_, v0_] := Exp[-(1/2) (r/rCloud)^2] r Exp[-(1/2) (v/v0)^2]  v;
ΔΦ[v_] := (2 π )/λ c (4 (v*t)^2)/(rBeam)^2;
```

I want to weight `ΔΦ` by `ρ` and `γ`. I do so by defining a function `Awfc` that numerically integrates the product of the three functions over `v` and `r` and divides by the numerical integral over the two weighting functions:

```
Awfc[rDet_?NumericQ, v0_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[ γ[r,v,rDet]*ρ[r,v,v0]* Exp[I ΔΦ[v]], {r,0,∞}, {v,0,∞ }}]/
   NIntegrate[ γ[r,v,rDet]*ρ[r,v,v0], {r,0,∞}, {v,0,∞}}];
```

I calculate `Awfc` for some parameters `rDet` and `v0`

```
AwfcTable = 
  ParallelTable[
    {rDet, Awfc[rDet, 0.5 v0], Awfc[rDet, v0], Awfc[rDet,2 v0], Awfc[rDet,3.7 v0]}, 
    {rDet,0.0005,0.010,0.0005}];
```

using these values for the other parameters:

```
tDet = 0.7;
t = 0.230;
rCloud = 0.0025;
λ =  780 10 ^-9;
c = λ/20;
v0 = 0.00588;
rDet = 0.008/2;         
rBeam = 0.015;
```

All kernels throw warnings:

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

I think that `ΔΦ` is a hightly osciallating function so I don't see a way to fix this problem.

I use `TableForm[Abs[AwfcTable]]` to get the amplitude of the complex numbers in `AwfcTable`. The problem with the output is, that this amplitude is significantly larger than 1, especially for larger `v0` and small `rDet`. The function `ΔΦ` I am calculating the weighted mean of, has a maximum amplitude of 1 so I think the weighted mean should also have a maximum of 1. (The complex phase is consistent with what I expect from a different approach to the problem I did using MATLAB)

Is there something wrong with my reasoning (meaning that the result *Mathematica* gives is actually correct), or is does the fault lie with my implementation of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems were apparently caused by how the parameters were chosen.

In the problem at hand they represent physical quantities: parameters starting with `r` have dimension meter, those with `t` have dimension second and those starting with `v` have meter/second.

A much more resonable choice would be to use milimeters and miliseconds, i.e. multiplying all variables starting with `r` or `t` by a factor $1000$:

```
tDet = 700;
t = 230;
rCloud = 2.5;
c = λ/20;
v0 = 0.00588;
rDet = 8.0/2;
rBeam = 15;
```

This way in `AwfcTable` instead of the intervall one can use a different intervall, thus both avoiding the `NIntegrate::slwcon` warnings and yielding reasonable results for `Abs[AwfcTable]`$\leq 1$:

```
AwfcTable = ParallelTable[
   {rDet, Awfc[rDet, 0.5 v0], Awfc[rDet, v0], Awfc[rDet, 2 v0],  Awfc[rDet, 3.7 v0]},
    {rDet, 0.5, 10, 0.5}];
```

Comment: Changing the units results into what I meant by scaling in my answer! Physics and math both prefers to be in agreement most of the time.

Answer (score 5):

**Observation:**

First of all I think it is always a useful trick to plot your *problematic* integrand if possible. It gives us often the clue in case `NIntegrate` complained about the particular integrand. If we can track down the issue we can often come up with a remedy.
Given the following input if one sweeps over the `rDet` we get the following plots. Given your the quantity of interest which is ratio of two integrals.

```
Awfc[rDet_?NumericQ, v0_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[ γ[r,v,rDet]*ρ[r,v,v0]* Exp[I ΔΦ[v]],
{r,0,∞}, {v,0,∞ }}]/NIntegrate[ γ[r,v,rDet]*ρ[r,v,v0], {r,0,∞}, {v,0,∞}}];
```

[image]

**Conclusion:**

The numerator integral involves a complex function that rapidly becomes zero. The denominator is a real function that is also fast asymptotic. Hence for faster evaluation of your `ParallelTable` we can `NIntegrate` on a shorter interval. But in this case we can also do the full integration by tuning up some options. One can also scale the integrals beforehand as that will avoid numerical error to some extent.

```
AwfcInf[rDet_?NumericQ, v0_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[γ[r, v, rDet]*ρ[r, v, v0]*Exp[I ΔΦ[v]], 
{r, 0, Infinity}, {v, 0,Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 12,PrecisionGoal -> 30]/
(Re@NIntegrate[γ[r, v, rDet]*ρ[r, v, v0], {r, 0,Infinity}, {v, 0, Infinity},  
AccuracyGoal -> 12,PrecisionGoal -> 30])
```

Now you can call your table safely.

```
AwfcTable = ParallelTable[{rDet, AwfcInf[rDet, 0.5 v0], AwfcInf[rDet, v0],
AwfcInf[rDet, 2 v0],AwfcInf[rDet, 3.7 v0]},
{rDet, 0.0005,0.010, 0.0005}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {11.972305, Null}

Ans now this is how the last four entries vary in `AwfcTable` as you sweep over `rDet`.
[image]

**Going faster:**
Following the visual observation and the conclusion we can try to decrease the integration interval considerably! We first check for the numerator and denominator integral for convergence.

```
NIntegrate[γ[r, v, rDet]*ρ[r, v, v0]*
    Exp[I ΔΦ[v]], {r, 0, Evaluate@#}, {v, 0,Evaluate@#}, AccuracyGoal -> 20, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 30] & /@ {.1, .25, 1, 10, 100, Infinity}
```

> {1.98046*10^-10 + 1.57094*10^-12 I, 1.98046*10^-10 + 1.57094*10^-12 I,
>     1.98046*10^-10 + 1.57094*10^-12 I, 
>    1.98046*10^-10 + 1.57094*10^-12 I, 1.98046*10^-10 + 1.57094*10^-12 I,
>     1.98046*10^-10 + 1.57094*10^-12 I}

The numerator converges to even if we replace `Infinity` with $0.25$! Now do the same for the denominator integral.

```
Re@NIntegrate[γ[r, v, rDet]*ρ[r, v, v0], {r, 0,Evaluate@#},
{v, 0, Evaluate@#}, AccuracyGoal -> 20, 
PrecisionGoal -> 30] & /@ {.1, .25, 1, 10, 100, Infinity}
```

> {1.98058*10^-10, 1.98058*10^-10, 1.60127*10^-10, 1.60127*10^-10, 
>    1.60127*10^-10, 1.60127*10^-10}

The numerator converges even if we assume an integration limit of $1$ in both dimensions in place of `Infinity`. Following this we can have a new `Awfc` that will be *much faster* than your infinite integrals. `Re` is used in the denominator to get rid of the the imaginary part that arises due to numerical error.

```
Clear[Awfc];
Awfc[rDet_?NumericQ, v0_?NumericQ] := 
  Quiet@(NIntegrate[γ[r, v, rDet]*ρ[r, v, v0]*
       Exp[I ΔΦ[v]], {r, 0, .25}, {v,0, .25},
       AccuracyGoal -> 12,PrecisionGoal -> 30]/
       (Re@NIntegrate[γ[r, v, rDet]*ρ[r, v, v0], {r, 0,1}, {v, 0, 1},
       AccuracyGoal -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 30]));
```

Testing how fast it is.

```
AwfcTableLess = 
   ParallelTable[{rDet, Awfc[rDet, 0.5 v0], Awfc[rDet, v0], 
     Awfc[rDet, 2 v0], Awfc[rDet, 3.7 v0]}, {rDet, 0.0005, 0.010, 
     0.0005}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {3.879663, Null}

Compare the results with above plot.
[image]

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Your answer does indeed speed things up. But speed isn't really the problem here: The settings for `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` do alter the `Arg[]` of the values in `AwfcTable` and this value is also really important. Also, if you look at `TableForm[Abs[AwfcInfTable]]` you'll see that these values are greater than 1 but the weighted function `Exp[I ΔΦ[v]` is smaller or equal to 1.

Comment: @frankundfrei good to hear few feed backs from you! Will give a deeper look at the issue here. Give me some time ;)

Comment: I think I found the mistake I've made. I'm looking into it a bit further and will post an answer if it turns out it is actually working. Thanks anyway so far, I did learn from your answer!

Comment: By the way I noticed just now that `Exp[I \[CapitalDelta]\[CapitalPhi][v]]` is a function of single variable and probably not absolutely integrable with respect to your 2D weight function `γ[r, v, rDet]*ρ[r, v, v0]`.